# Year Make Model Javascript HTML link to URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, drop-down-menu

Trying to make a year make a model drop-down link to a different URL for each final selection. Not sure how to do it.

Example: Once 1975 and CB400F are selected browser is directed to a URL such as motorcyclewebsite.com/CB400F0-SUPER-SPORT-1975-USA/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('select[name*="[]"]').each(function(){
             
            var attribute = {
            '1975': ['Choose Model', 'CB400F', 'CB550F', 'CB750F', 'GL1000'],
            '1976': ['Choose Model', 'CB400F','CB125', 'CL350K', 'EZ50', 'Gyro'],
            '1977': ['Choose Model', 'CB400F', 'CX500', 'GL650', 'XL100'],
            }
     
            


            $('select[name*="[]"]').change(function () {
            var $attribute = $(this).next('.attribute');
             
             
            var product = $(this).val(), lcns = attribute[product] || [];
           
            
            var html = $.map(lcns, function(lcn){
                return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + '</option>'
            }).join('');
           
           
           
           
            $attribute.html(html);
          
           
            });
        });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="input" action="test.php" method="post">
<div class="options">
    <select name="product[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm product">
        <option value="Select Year">Select Year</option>
        <option value="1975">1975</option>
        <option value="1976">1976</option>
        <option value="1977">1977</option>
    </select>
    <select name="att[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm attribute">
    </select>
    
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Thanks for any help

UPDATE: Does anyone know how to make a simple javascript to say:

if var product = X
and var attribute = Y

Then go to location HTTPS://.........

without having it construct a ULR,

Thanks

Comment: If you want to have a different url for each section then you will have to use "get" instead of "post" so that you pass the form value in through url parameters. In your php file (test.php) you will also need to refer to $_GET in order to determine what to show to your user.

Comment: If you want to redirect the user to a specific url which has already been created, then you will have the test.php file return a header with the "Redirect" value set to the url you want. For example: `<?php header("Location:  motorcyclewebsite.com/$_POST[product]-$_POST[att]") `.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you should be able to achieve this by adding the following code listed in the `.change()` handler below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // When either of the select values change, check for valid values on each:
    $('select').change(function() {

      var product = $('select.product').val();
      var attribute = $('select.attribute').val();

      // If valid values for both selects, then construct the URL and relocate the page
      // to that URL
      if(product && attribute) {
        console.log('loading http://motorcyclewebsite.com/'+attribute+'-SUPER-SPORT-'+product+'-USA/')
        location = 'http://motorcyclewebsite.com/'+attribute+'-SUPER-SPORT-'+product+'-USA/';
      }
    });

    $('select[name*="[]"]').each(function(){
        
      var attribute = {
      '1975': ['Choose Model', 'CB400F', 'CB550F', 'CB750F', 'GL1000'],
      '1976': ['Choose Model', 'CB400F','CB125', 'CL350K', 'EZ50', 'Gyro'],
      '1977': ['Choose Model', 'CB400F', 'CX500', 'GL650', 'XL100'],
      }
    
      


      $('select[name*="[]"]').change(function () {
      var $attribute = $(this).next('.attribute');
        
        
      var product = $(this).val(), lcns = attribute[product] || [];
      
      
      var html = $.map(lcns, function(lcn){
          return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + '</option>'
      }).join('');
      
      
      
      
      $attribute.html(html);
    
      
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="input" action="test.php" method="post">
<div class="options">
    <select name="product[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm product">
        <option value="Select Year">Select Year</option>
        <option value="1975">1975</option>
        <option value="1976">1976</option>
        <option value="1977">1977</option>
    </select>
    <select name="att[]" class="custom-select form-control-sm attribute">
    </select>
    
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Does any one know how to direct to a specific URL when the selection is made rather than having it build the url?

Comment: @Rufus you're welcome - can you give a bit more detail on where the specific URL will come from? Does `location = 'http://motorcyclewebsite.com/'+attribute+'-SUPER-SPORT-'+product+'-USA/';` not meet your requirements?

Comment: Hi Dacre, Thanks. The URL's will be slightly different from the combination of selections in the drop down menus. As an example, if 1975 and CB400F are selected then direct to https://www.denniskirk.com/1975-honda-cb400f-super-sport.mmy

Comment: @Rufus I see - where does this extra URL information come from? How is it supplied?

Comment: I was thinking I would just write it into the code when it's all ready

Comment: @Rufus ok - let me know if you need help with that. Hope the answer above has been of use :-)

Comment: Hi Dacre, some help would be great. What's the best way to contact you directly?